# Get color of individual pixels of images in pygame

Tags: python, image, image-processing, pygame

How can I get the colour values of pixels of an image that is blitted onto a pygame surface? Using Surface.get_at() only returns the color of the surface layer, not the image that has been blitted over it.

Comment: please provide a sample of your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `surface.get_at` is fine. 
Here is an example showing the difference when blitting an image without alpha channel.

```
import sys, pygame
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 320, 240
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
image = pygame.image.load("./img.bmp")
image_rect = image.get_rect()

screen.fill((0,0,0))
screen.blit(image, image_rect)
screensurf = pygame.display.get_surface()

while 1:

  for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN :
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        pxarray = pygame.PixelArray(screensurf)
        pixel = pygame.Color(pxarray[mouse[0],mouse[1]])
        print pixel
        print screensurf.get_at(mouse)

  pygame.display.flip()
```

Here, clicking on a red pixel will give :

```
(0, 254, 0, 0)
(254, 0, 0, 255)
```

The PixelArray returns a 0xAARRGGBB color component, while Color expect 0xRRGGBBAA. Also notice that the alpha channel of the screen surface is 255.

Comment: +1 Great answer! Just two things: you're mentioning `surface.getAt` and using `surface.get_at`. It might be confusing. Secondly, you're using an undefined variable `e` in the `pygame.display.flip` function. I'm not sure what it suppose to be and since it's to few characters to change I can't edit it myself.